# I can't SELECT a schema that was created in @jointable annotation in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I created a JoinTable as an annotation, therefore I don't have an entity for that database schema. Is that why I get this error:

"Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT it FROM itinerary_flight it WHERE it.itineraryTraveller_id = :id]. 
[15, 31] The abstract schema type 'itinerary_flight' is unknown.
[41, 65] The state field path 'it.itineraryTraveller_id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.".

Here where I create the jointable:`

```
@Entity
public class itineraryTraveller implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long Id;
private String departureLocation;
private String arrivalLocation;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//@JoinTable(name="ITINERARYTRAVELLER_FLIGHT")
@JoinTable(name = "itinerary_flight",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "itineraryTraveller_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "flightEntity_id")
 )
private List<flightEntity> flights;
```

And when I try to select that jointable I get that error message above. Here the query:

```
Query query= em.createQuery("SELECT it FROM Itinerary_flight it WHERE it.itineraryTraveller_id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", listOfItineraries.get(i).getId());
        List<flightEntity> list= query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Did you actually CREATE the schema for this entity? and does the TABLE exist? because the message implies that it doesn't. Just putting some annotation will NOT CREATE the schema without running a schema create step process

Comment: it exists!! when I go to Workbench I can see the table created and properly full. But the only place where I created the schema is in that @jointable annotation. So I dont have an entity for that table

Comment: @NeilStockton I think the problem is that the query is called in entityManager (but this join table does not have an entity). So how can I query a schema without entity manager???

Comment: In JPQL you cannot refer to some arbitrary table... you refer to an ENTITY like any JPQL reference will tell you. You could OTOH use a NATIVE QUERY and put SQL in there ... but then I see no point in doing that

Comment: so what do u recommend me?? create an entity for that jointable?

Comment: recommend u? Why not TELL PEOPLE what that query is trying to do?! that and read a JPQL tutorial of course

Comment: I am trying to Select all rows from that join table, to delete some of the ItinerariesTravellers according to their flightId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL like this would find all itineraries which have a flight

```
SELECT ti FROM TravellerItinerary ti JOIN ti.flights fl WHERE fl.id = :id
```

but then you don't post the related entity so to say more than that is not possible